# Referencing the (unreleased) activesupport 4.0 gem in a Gemfile

Tags: bundler, gemfile, ruby-on-rails-4

Is there a way to reference any of the Rails 4 gems (activesupport, activerecord, activemodel etc.) that sit in subdirectories of the Rails git repo on Github in a Gemfile? I have a library whose tests I want to run against activesupport 4, and since there is no released version of that gem I have to reference the git repo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just point Bundler to the git repository. Bundler will search for the gem in the root directory or in a directory that has the gems name.

```
source :rubygems

gem 'activerecord', :git => 'git@github.com:rails/rails.git'
```